# How to retrieve max id based on value from different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming I have 3 columns, ID, firstcolumn, secondcolumn.

I need to retrieve the max id of firstcolumn based on value from secondcolumn. This returned id must be the maximum id of firstcolumn but must still be less than or equal to the value from the secondcolumn per record.

Dataset:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+
| ID | firstcolumn | secondcolumn |
+----+-------------+--------------+
|  1 |          32 |           32 |
|  1 |          32 |           35 |
|  1 |          32 |           38 |
|  1 |          34 |           32 |  
|  1 |          34 |           35 |  
|  1 |          34 |           38 |  
|  1 |          39 |           32 |  
|  1 |          39 |           35 |  
|  1 |          39 |           38 |  
|  2 |          12 |           12 |  
|  2 |          12 |           17 |  
|  2 |          18 |           12 |  
|  2 |          18 |           17 |  
+----+-------------+--------------+
```

Resulting Dataset

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID | firstcolumn | secondcolumn | resultcolumn |  
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |          32 |           32 |           32 |  
|  1 |          32 |           35 |           34 |  
|  1 |          32 |           38 |           34 |  
|  1 |          34 |           32 |           32 |  
|  1 |          34 |           35 |           34 |  
|  1 |          34 |           38 |           34 |  
|  1 |          39 |           32 |           32 |  
|  1 |          39 |           35 |           34 |  
|  1 |          39 |           38 |           34 |  
|  2 |          12 |           12 |           12 |  
|  2 |          12 |           17 |           12 |  
|  2 |          18 |           12 |           12 |  
|  2 |          18 |           17 |           12 |  
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: HI, and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you explain what the purpose of this query is? There might be a better way to structure the data.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: Can you check your expected result? This row doesn't match your description: `|  1 |          39 |           32 |           33 |` The result should be `32`?

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, thanks for spotting that out. I've edited accordingly

Comment: @Schwern I'll try explain what I'm trying to do to the best of my ability. This table is querying a transactional history of funds accrued for a project. In this table we have a version id which is logged anytime the project (ID) is updated. The two columns in this table show the version id of the project when the employee (secondcolumn) was changed as well as the version id of the project when the amount was updated (firstcolumn). I need to query every time the employee changes and retain the transactional history of the amounts accrued per employee change which the resulting column does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation translates to a Correlated Scalar Subquery:

```
select *,
  ( select max(firstcolumn) -- maximum id of firstcolumn
    from tab as t2
    where t1.id = t2.id
      and t2.firstcolumn <= t1.secondcolumn  -- less than or equal to secondcolumn
  )
from tab as t1
```